# How to make Shiny wait until you hit submit

Tags: r, shiny

So I am building an R Shinny app that runs a simulation study and so every time the user changes one of the inputs I don't want the app to start running the simulations until they hit a submit button. How can I achieve this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
The UI file:

#ui.R
# Define UI for random distribution application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("ORR Simulator"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the random distribution type
  # and number of observations to generate. Note the use of the
  # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Select the XXX.csv file',
                accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
          fileInput('file2', 'Select the YYY.csv file',
                accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
     numericInput("S", "Number of simulations to run:", 100),

       mainPanel(
plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))
```

And so I would like for there to be a button that says something like submit and once they push that the actual R programs runs rather than running as soon as they change any input.

Comment: Check out `?submitButton` or `?actionButton`

Answer (score 7):

On the UI side you want to use something like `actionButton`.  On the server side you want to use an `observe` or an `observeEvent`.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("submit button example"),
    column(4,
      textInput(
        inputId = "location_id",
        label = "Enter stuff: ",
        value = "param1"
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "submit_loc",
        label = "Submit"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(
      eventExpr = input[["submit_loc"]],
      handlerExpr = {
        print("PRESSED") #simulation code can go here
      }
    )
  }
)
```

With this setup, your simulation code only runs when shiny detects a change with the `actionButton`.  Your other inputs can be changed without triggering the simulation code to run -- you can change the `textInput` and it won't trigger any of the simulation code to run.

Also note, the `print` statement will not show up directly in the shiny app, it'll show up in your R console.

Comment: Also, I get this error when using your code: ERROR: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Comment: @RustyStatistician it's hard for me to place it in your code when you didn't post your server.R code.  I changed my example to have a full fledged self-contained minimal reproducible example.  

That error code isn't caused by my original example -- I suspect you might have missed a comma somewhere in inserting my original example.

Comment: so here is an updated error message: Error in observeEvent(eventExpr = input[["submit_loc"]], handler = { : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments

Comment: It appears you're using `handler` instead of `handlerExpr`

Comment: Right now when you press the button all it does is print to your R console (I added a note about this).  If you want something to happen in shiny, you can insert your shiny code or code to run your simulations inside the `handlerExpr`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you. Shiny waited for the first submit and when I typed a text a second time it immedialtely began to calculate.
The solution I found is easy. Instead of using observeEvent you need to use eventReactive. I found it [here](https://riptutorial.com/shiny/example/32341/eventreactive)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Example eventReactive"),
  
  mainPanel(
    
    # input field
    textInput("user_text", label = "Enter some text:", placeholder = "Please enter some text."),

    # submit button
    actionButton("submit", label = "Submit"),
    
    # display text output
    textOutput("text"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # reactive expression
  text_reactive <- eventReactive( input$submit, {
    input$user_text
  })
  
  # text output
  output$text <- renderText({
    text_reactive()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```